# ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-9.6/share/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory

Tags: django, postgresql, centos7

I want to deploy my project to VPS Centos7. But i am getting error while installing postgres. When i type

```
create extension postgis;
```

Getting error

> ERROR:  could not open extension control file
>   "/usr/pgsql-9.6/share/extension/postgis.control": No such file or
>   directory

Because postgis.contol is located in another place,

```
find /usr -name postgis.control

/usr/share/pgsql/extension/postgis.control
```

But postgres trying to create it from `/usr/pgsql-9.6/share/extension/postgis.control`

**This question already was asked before, but my problem is other.**

Comment: Just install PostGIS in the proper directory - where is the problem?

Comment: Was this ever solved? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

For me, I run below command in Ubuntu, and the issue was resolved.

```
sudo apt install postgresql-10-postgis-scripts
```

then run

```
 CREATE EXTENSION postgis
```

It works fine for me.I hope it helps.

Comment: Do you know how you would go about doing this with yum?

Comment: were you able to figure it out for yum/dnf ? @RichardMcCormick

Comment: @darthbaba I just ended up using a Docker image. Think you would have to pull the binaries to do a direct install